# Run javascript once for website instead of adding to whitelist in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I run with javascript disabled by default and I whitelist sites like superuser or gmail as needed. Sometimes though, a blog that I'll never read again requires js to get anything more than a blank page (argh). It doesn't make sense that I should have to put a permanent whitelist entry when I'll never visit that site again and just want to read a blog post.

Is there a way to "run all javascript this time" akin to how it's done for plugins? Is there an extension that manages javascript whitelisting?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ScriptNo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptno/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf) in the chrome store.  The extension makes managing a JavaScript whitelist much easier and includes the allow scripts for this session feature.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks like a very complete extension with a lot of features.  

But, it seems to ignore all of my existing whitelisting. I'd rather have something that works *with* Chrome's list rather than sits over top of it. I might make the switch if nothing else comes about.